# Gtk python нужно поставить виджет в textview и задать ему ширину родителя

Tags: python, gui, gtk

вставить в textview что-нибудь поверх текста не проблема, проблема - экспандить это по ширине и высоте.
замечу что находясь в любом другом контейнере код:

```
    scrolled.set_hexpand(True)
    scrolled.set_vexpand(True)
    scrolled.expand = True
```

в полной мере растягивает виджет под размер родителя.
Нужно сделать то же самое для textview (Multiline Text Editor)

как вариант можно задавать виджету определённый размер, но настоящий размер textview в пикселях достать неизвестно как

Answer (score 0):

```
    def resize(widget, r):
        scrolled.set_size_request(r.width, r.height)

    self.textview.tv.connect_after('size-allocate', resize)
```